# Объявления функций js

Tags: javascript

Поясните пожалуйста в чем разница объявления функций

```
var func = function(){
//some code
}

и 

var func = (function(){
//some code
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае мы лишь определяем функцию и записываем ее в переменную `func`. После можно будет использовать `func()` для вызова функции.

Во втором же случае мы определяем функцию и сразу же ее вызываем и ответ записывается в переменную `func`.